# Check if all record columns of 2 Tables/Query are equal

Tags: sql-server-2005

In SQL Server 2005, I would like to make one query that checks if all record columns of 2 tables are the same,
Example:

```
declare @tbl1 table(col nvarchar(50))
declare @tbl2 table(col nvarchar(50))

insert into @tbl1
    select '11' union select '22'
insert into @tbl2
    select '22' 
--should return false
```

---

```
declare @tbl1 table(col nvarchar(50))
declare @tbl2 table(col nvarchar(50))

insert into @tbl1
    select '11' 
insert into @tbl2
    select '11' union select '22'
--should return false
```

---

```
declare @tbl1 table(col nvarchar(50))
declare @tbl2 table(col nvarchar(50))

insert into @tbl1
    select '11' union select '22'
insert into @tbl2
    select '11' union select '22'
--should return true
```

Using `IN` clause, or `LEFT JOIN` i'm only able to check if all record columns in one of the tables are present on the other.

Edit: Order is irrelevant

Comment: Strictly for completeness, you could also use the SQL Server command-line utility, `tablediff` for this purpose.  http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22385/checking-if-2-tables-on-different-servers-have-the-same-exact-data/22396#22396

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS
         ( SELECT * FROM table1
           EXCEPT 
           SELECT * FROM table2
         ) 
             AND NOT EXISTS 
         ( SELECT * FROM table2
           EXCEPT 
           SELECT * FROM table1
         ) 
         THEN 'True' ELSE 'False'
       END AS result ;
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below will convert all the values of a column to a string which it then hashes. Running this code on both tables and comparing the two hashes will tell you if they are identical or if there is a difference.

```
SELECT HASHBYTES('MD5', CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), col)) 
FROM @tbl1  FOR XML PATH('')
```

Comment: humm, doesn't work if is not in the same order.
Forgot to mention.